# RadioButtonList selection in view and edit mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a radio button list which should be display in view and edit mode in web form. When the page load, the radio button should have selected value based on the value fetched from database(IsAnimal of type bit).

When user switch to edit mode, the radio button default selected value should be the same as view mode as well. The selected value of radio button in edit mode will change when user switch it. But what i am having here is that after the selectedindex_changed, the pre_render will keep trigger. If i do if(!Page.IsPostBack) in prerender then the default selection value is null in edit mode.

```js
protected void Form_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  RadioButtonList rbViewIsAnimal = (RadioButtonList) fvForm.FindControl("rbViewIsAnimal");
  RadioButtonList rbEditIsAnimal = (RadioButtonList) fvForm.FindControl("rbEditIsAnimal");

  if (txtIsAnimal.Value == "True") {
    if (rbViewIsAnimal != null) {
      rbViewIsAnimal.Items.FindByValue("1").Selected = true;
    }
    if (rbEditIsAnimal != null) {
      rbEditIsAnimal.Items.FindByValue("1").Selected = true;
    }
  } else {
    if (rbViewIsAnimal != null) {
      rbViewIsAnimal.Items.FindByValue("0").Selected = true;
    }
    if (rbEditIsAnimal != null) {
      rbEditIsAnimal.Items.FindByValue("0").Selected = true;
    }
  }
}


protected void rbEditIsAnimal_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  RadioButtonList rbEditIsAnimal = (RadioButtonList) fvForm.FindControl("rbEditIsAnimal");
  TextBox txtEditAnimalDescription = (TextBox) fvForm.FindControl("txtEditAnimalDescription");

  if (txtIsAnimal.Value == "True") {
    txtEditAnimalDescription.Enabled = false;
    txtEditAnimalDescription.Text = string.Empty;
  } else {
    txtEditAnimalDescription.Enabled = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<ItemTemplate>
  <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="txtIsAnimal" Value='<%# Bind("IsAnimal") %>' />
  <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="rbViewIsAnimal" Enabled="false">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Not Animal" Value="0" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Animal" Value="1" />
  </asp:RadioButtonList>
</ItemTemplate>

<EditItemTemplate>
  <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="txtIsAnimal" />
  <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="rbEditIsAnimal" Value='<%# Bind("IsAnimal") %>' AutoPostBack="true">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Not Animal" Value="1" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Animale" Value="0" />
  </asp:RadioButtonList>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

Comment: can that code be moved to the Page_Load .

Comment: @MethodMan which code do you mean? if you mean the code in pre_render, the outcome is that the radio button list in edititemtemplate will not have any default selected value and the selectedvalue in itemtemplate is missing as well if cancel button is click in edit mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found a sample [here](http://dilipkakadiya.blogspot.ca/2011/11/radiobuttonlist-dropdownlist-in.html) that looks like what you need. the sample data has four columns, and there's a radiobuttonlist and a dropdownlist in the 3rd and 4th columns, so the code below uses datarow cells [2] and [3]. i added a few comments.

```
// i believe this fires on load *and* when editing.
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  DataRowView dRowView = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
    // editing:
    if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
    {
      // find the controls.
      RadioButtonList rblGender = (RadioButtonList)e.Row.FindControl("rbGenderEdit");
      DropDownList ddlStatus = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlStatusEdit");
      // set the values.
      rblGender.SelectedValue = dRowView[2].ToString();
      ddlStatus.SelectedValue = dRowView[3].ToString();
    }
  }           
}

protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
  // find the controls.
  RadioButtonList rblGender = (RadioButtonList)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("rbGenderEdit");
  DropDownList ddlStatus = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("ddlStatusEdit");
  // set the values.
  SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters["Sex"].DefaultValue = rblGender.SelectedValue;
  SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters["MaritalStauts"].DefaultValue = ddlStatus.SelectedValue;
}
```